# Magento 1.9 wont update

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.9

I have uploaded [Better Blog](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-3-1.html) onto my magento store, we created a couple of Blog posts using it, but when we went back in to make changes, like spelling mistakes, it wont update, even though the changes show within the editor?

I have tried flushing the magento Cache, even within the FTP var/cache

Comment: I don't have experience with that specific extension, but when you log in to make the changes, are you sure you're changing the same store as you're viewing on the front end? As you're probably aware, Magento can run multiple store views so it might be possible your front end is viewing a different store ID. Just a thought.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?